# What word is there for a man and a woman who have children together but are not in a romantic relationship and were never married?

Tags: kinship-terms

I am trying to find a word in any language that would indicate the relationship of two people specifically because they have mated/bred/procreated together.

The closest I can find is co-parent but this isn't a one-word solution and seems to imply that both parties are currently actively parenting.

Looking to replace "my son's father" or "my son's mother."

Comment: In the U.S., the term "birth parents" is applied to the sources of a baby's DNA—identified individually as "birth mother" and "birth father."

Comment: Similar to @SvenYargs suggestion, you could also say something like :  they are *John Smith's biological parents*.

Comment: *Co-parent* is one word not two, sand we do not accept request for words "in any language".

Comment: The terms "baby mama" and "baby daddy" came into common use because there wasn't already a term, except for the more formal, less snappy versions you want to replace. Options get wordier and more clinical from there, like."former procreative partner".

Comment: @1006a The problem with those terms is that once the child grows to adulthood they become ambiguous. I'm sure I've heard adults referring to "my baby mama (or daddy)" to mean the other parent of their child but it seems also to be used in "my Shania's baby daddy" to mean the biological father of a child (which is what the OP is looking for). When Shania grows up and has her own baby there will be ambiguity in the term "Shania's baby daddy".

Answer (score 1):

"Ex-partner" or simply "ex" might work, if the two parents used to be romantically involved with one another. I mention this because you are specifically looking for a replacement word for "my child's other parent".
See the first definition here [in case this is a matter of English not being your first language - otherwise I'll assume you are already familiar with this term]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex

Comment: An answer on EL&U is expected to be authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct. It's best if you edit your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition (linked to the source). Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and read about how to answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck thank you for the advice. I have read the English StackExchange info and edited my answer.